# Questions about using slider with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts, slider

As you can see from the following JSFiddle, I am attempting to test slider functionality simultaneously on a couple of charts with small arrays of data. The slider works fine, except for the very first tick for the line chart. The chart initializes correctly and shows the right starting line series, and as you move the slider to the right and back to the left, the line chart series does change correctly. However, when you move the slider back to the starting point on the far left, the line chart does not fully move back to the starting series. The last value should be 268.77, as you see from when the chart first initializes, but it gets stuck on the second line series and has an ending value of 271.13, even when the slider is moved back to the starting position. Here is my slider code, which works fine for the pie chart:

```
$("#slider").slider({
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: pieallocations.length - 1,
step: 1,
slide: function(event, ui) {
  finalpie = [];
  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < funds.length, j < pieallocations.length; i++, j++) 
  {
    finalpie.push({
      name: funds[i],
      y: pieallocations[ui.value][j]
    });
  }
  finalline = lineseries[ui.value];
  piechart.series[0].setData(finalpie);
  linechart.series[0].setData(finalline);
}
});
```

On a separate note, is there an efficient way for me to embed these arrays with subarrays into CSV or JSON files to query externally instead of including the data in the chart code itself?

http://jsfiddle.net/ksalehizadeh/cwd3cknq/1/

Thanks very much.

Comment: It looks that using $.extend should solve your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cwd3cknq/3/

Regarding csv/json with Highcharts: 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

if this comment will suit your need I will post it as an answer

Comment: This is great regarding the $.extend functionality, thank you @GrzegorzBlachliński. Does that work if I want to add an additional series to the line chart? Regarding the use of JSON or CSV to house the arrays with sub-arrays, do you have the time to show me how this would work with my specific situation? Even if you could provide an example of the code to pull the pie chart allocation data from an external file as arrays, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use $.extend with additional series in line chart. I have prepared an example of loading CSV file to the pie chart: http://jsfiddle.net/b14t521z/31/

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzBlachliński. I have the information I need at this point.